# Most used word for "quince" in classical Latin

Tags: classical-latin, late-latin, spanish

A typical Spanish dessert is the quince jelly (Spanish: *carne/dulce de membrillo*), which is also known as *codoñate* in areas of Catalan influence. Now, the Spanish word for quince is *membrillo*, which comes from Latin *melimēlum* 'honey apple'. But Catalan *codonyat* comes from the Catalan word for quince: *codony*, and this one comes from Latin *cotoneum, cotonei* 'quince'.

So it seems that the proper word for *quince* in Latin was *cotoneum* but I was wondering how is that the Spanish word *membrillo* comes from apparently a different fruit. So:

- Is it possible that the Latin words *melimelum* and *cotoneum* meant the same thing in Classical Latin? Or maybe the word *melimelum* came to mean *quince* in Late or Medieval Latin?
- Was *cotoneum* indeed the most used word for *quince*?

Comment: Fun etymological fact: English "marmalade" comes (through Portuguese *marmelo*) from *melimelum*.

Comment: Fun non-etymological fact: I had a hard time writing this question because in Spanish "quince" means "fifteen" and somehow my brain rejected the idea that the same word meant something completely different in English. :)

Comment: @brianpck I lke your derivation of 'marmalade'. It's new to me, so I'll add it to the forty or so others that occur in English myth! (it's a standing joke, as you probably know, that no-one really knows the word's origin). More seriously, though, it's interesting that Charlie's 'quince jelly' is used here in England as an alternative to marmalade on your breakfast toast.

Comment: An extra note on its etymology can be found at https://www.etymonline.com/word/marmalade.

Comment: For the word melimelum, see L & S:-

Answer (score 7):

According to the *[Etimologia botanica](http://www.summagallicana.it/Etimologia_botanica/etimologia_botanica/etimologia_botanica_PING_PY.htm)* of Alexandre de Théis, these words originally referred to two different species. On the one hand, *melimelum* comes from the Greek μελίμηλον, and this originally belonged to the species *pyrus paradisiaca*:

> **P. paradisiaca** (*pomme de paradis*). Par allusion à son goût doux et
>   agréable. Les Grecs nommoient ce fruit, dans le même sens, μελίμηλον,
>   pomme de miel.

Quince, on the other hand, is the species *pyrus cydonia*:

> **P. cydonia.** Originaire de la ville de Cydon, en Crète, aujourd’hui la Canée. Les Latins l’appeloient malus-cotonea. Son fruit est couvert
>   de coton avant sa maturité.
>   *Le cotonea*, dit Pline, liv. 15, chap. 11, que les Grecs nomment cydoni, a été apporté de l’île de Crète.
>  De *cydonia* nous avons
>   fait *coing*, et de coing les Anglois ont fait *quince*.

**Translation:**

> **P. paradisiaca** (*apple of paradise*). Alluding to its sweet and pleasant flavor, the Greeks called this fruit, in the same sense, μελίμηλον,
>   honey apple.
>   **P. cydonia.** Originally from the village Cydon, Crete, currently the city Chania. The Latins called it malus-cotonea. Its fruit is covered with cotton before coming to maturity.
>   *Le cotonea*, says Pliny, book. 15, chap. 11, which the Greeks call cydoni, was brought from the isle of Crete.
>  From *cydonia* we have
>   derived *coing*, and from coing the English have derived *quince*.

Answer (score 6):

This is from Plin. Nat. Hist. Book 15, ix, 37 —

*his proxima amplitudine mala quae vocamus **cotonea** et Graece cydonea, e Creta insula advecta. incurvatos trahunt ramos prohibentque crescere parentem. plura eorum genera: chrysomela incisuris distincta, colore ad aurum inclinato, qui candidior nostratia cognominat, odoris praestantissimi*

— which, answering the second part of your question, seems to remove any doubt about *cotoneum* being the proper word for a quince.

However, I can't find *melimelum* anywhere, either directly through a search of the relevant books in Pliny's Natural History or `Packhum`, and I wonder where the word occurs?

Comment: Horace “post hoc me docuit melimela rubere minorem
ad lunam delecta”

Answer (score 5):

Very strangely, there is no entry for melimelum in (the electronic version of) L&S. I do not have the print version before me at the moment, but there are lots of good references (Pliny and others) in Gaffiot:

https://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=melimelum

and in Georges:

http://www.zeno.org/Zeno/0/Suche?q=melimelum&k=Georges-1913

EDIT: L&S do have it, but only as a plural:

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmelimela

Comment: Interesting that the flower of the Coing/Quince has a separate name from the fruit. In your first link, lower down the page, *melinum* scent of quince; *melinus* quince flower. (compare: Damask Rose, scent of which is called Attar)

Comment: *Melinus* 3 (quince coloured, quince oil, eye ointment etc) clearly shown as a loan word: L&S  http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DM%3Aentry+group%3D22%3Aentry%3Dmelinus3

Answer (score 3):

Relevant passages:

“Tum sive mala cydonia, quae percocta sublaturus sit ...” (Columella)

“Quaeque suos curvant matura cydonia ramos” (Ovid)

“Insecuta sunt Cydonia etiam mala spinis confixa, ut echinos efficeren” (Petronius)

“ etenim sic flore iuventae
induimur vultus, ut in arbore saepe notavi
cerea sub tenui lucere cydonia lana.” (Calpurnicus Silicus)

“nec hoc praetereo, quod ex fructibus arborum illi sunt frigidiores, quorum sucus imitatur vini saporem, ut mala seu simplicia seu granata vel **cydonia, quae cotonea vocat Cato**” (Macrobius) [emphasis mine - Alex B.]

“Praeterea malorum genera exquirenda maxime Scaudiana, Matiana, orbiculata, Cestina, Pelusiana, Amerina, Syrica, melimela, Cydonia: quorum genera tria sunt, struthia, chrysomelina, mustea” (Columnella)

etc.

However,

> “The identification of the 'Cydonian apples' (μῆλα κυδώνια/mêla kydṓnia) or the Lat. mala cotonea - Italian cotogna denotes quince - with the quince (Cydonia oblonga) is **at the very least dubious**” (New Pauly) [emphasis mine - Alex B.].

And, most importantly:

[image]

I wonder what it looks like at L’Orto dei Frutti Dimenticati.